# AngularJS GoogleMap Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create an Angular directive to display Google Maps.

Here is my directive:

```
'use strict';

var CartoBundle = angular.module('CartoBundle', []);

CartoBundle.directive('cartoBundleMap', function() {

var map;

return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    template: '<section id="map"></section>',
    scope: {
        zoom: "@",
        zoomControl: "=",
        fullScreenControl: "=",
        mapTypeControl: "=",
        scaleControl: "=",
        streetViewControl: "=",
        mapTypeId: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.52863469527167,2.43896484375),
            zoom: 6,
            zoomControl : true,
            fullscreenControl : true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            mapTypeId: "hybrid"
        };

        if (scope.zoom) options.zoom = scope.zoom * 1;
        if (scope.zoomControl) options.zoomControl = scope.zoomControl;
        if (scope.fullScreenControl) options.fullScreenControl = scope.fullScreenControl;
        if (scope.mapTypeControl) options.mapTypeControl = scope.mapTypeControl;
        if (scope.scaleControl) options.scaleControl = scope.scaleControl;
        if (scope.streetViewControl) options.streetViewControl = scope.streetViewControl;
        if (scope.mapTypeId) options.mapTypeId = scope.mapTypeId;

        map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], options);
    },
};
});
```

When I make a test with the following HTML it display the map with all the controls (it works):

```
<carto-bundle-map></carto-bundle-map>
```

Moreover when I try to setup text values it works as well :

```
<carto-bundle-map
    map-type-id="satellite"
></carto-bundle-map>
```

But when I try to setup booleans values it does not (my controls remains) :

```
<carto-bundle-map 
    zoom-control="false"
    full-screen-control="false"
    map-type-control="false"
    scale-control="false"
    street-view-control="false"
    map-type-id="satellite"
></carto-bundle-map>
```

Last things I can say is that if I tweak the controls to false directly within the directive it works and my controls disappear.

I read somewhere it was because I had to set the scopes with "equals" but it is already the case :

```
scope: {
    zoom: "@",
    zoomControl: "=",
    fullScreenControl: "=",
    mapTypeControl: "=",
    scaleControl: "=",
    streetViewControl: "=",
    mapTypeId: "@"
},
```

Can somebody help as I a beginner with angularjs.

Regards

Comment: There are plenty of libraries available that let you use Google Maps in your Angular application (like: https://ngmap.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found why it was not working.

It is because if scope.attribute is equal to false it will never validate the if condition.

I modified the code as follow :

```
if (!angular.isUndefined(scope.zoom)) options.zoom = scope.zoom * 1;
```

Hope this can help somebody later.

Regards